# How to retrieve emails directly from Outlook 2010 inbox for multiple users, for a VSTO Outlook add-in

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, exchange-server, outlook-addin

Currently creating an Outlook 2010 add-in using C# in VSTO (VS 2017), would like to know how to retrieve the emails directly from the inbox for automated scanning of phishing URLs of incoming messages. This add-in will be installed for multiple user accounts and PCs. I would be able to connect to the exchange server directly with server credentials and EWS but because it is for multiple low privileged users, is there a way to make sure that their user account info is the only credentials required without having to connect to the exchange server ?

Here is the sample code I found for connecting directly to exchange server:

```
using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data;
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013);
service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("USERNAME", "PASSWORD", "DOMAIN");
service.Url = new Uri("EXCHANGE_WEBSERVICE_URL");

Folder inbox = Folder.Bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.Inbox);
if (inbox.UnreadCount &gt; 0)
{
    ItemView view = new ItemView(inbox.UnreadCount);
    view.PropertySet = PropertySet.IdOnly;
    FindItemsResults&lt;Item&gt; results = service.FindItems(inbox.Id, view);

    foreach (Item item in results.Items)
    {
        EmailMessage email = EmailMessage.Bind(service, new ItemId(item.Id.UniqueId.ToString()));

        //PROCESS EMAIL MESSAGE 
        email.IsRead = true;
        email.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AlwaysOverwrite);
    }
}
```

Credits to creator for the sample codes

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no reason to use EWS in a COM addin. Firstly, you will need to prompt the user for and store the credentials. Secondly, OOM lets open other user's folders by calling `Namespace.GetSharedFolder` (assuming you have the rights to the other user's folder).

Comment: Hi @Dmitry Thanks for answering my question, what is the real difference between a COM add-in and a VSTO add-in? i have tried researching about it but i am still unable to grasp what the differences are.

Comment: As far as Outlook is concerned, there is none. VSTO is just a wrapper that makes creating COM add-ins easier.